# ERROR Unkown database: DATABASE_URL after overriding the DATABASE_URL in the heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to connect two Heroku apps to one database. So I overrided the DATABASE_URL. now the heroku config as:

```
=== muse-me Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:                postgres://rbbcoxizviewiu:taJsBZf...
GEM_PATH:                    vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL: postgres://jnlltenwyvmdup:Q5Doaw...
LANG:                        en_US.UTF-8
PATH:                        bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
RACK_ENV:                    production
RAILS_ENV:                   production
```

Then I run

```
heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL
```

It gave me an error:

```
!    Unknown database: DATABASE_URL. Valid options are: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL
```

What should I do? Do I really connect to the database with the DATABASE_URL?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

"DATABASE_URL" is just a placeholder for "HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL". If you run:

```
heroku pg:psql HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL
```

That should work because you're explicitly telling pg which database url to use. To be able to use that command without specifying the db, you need to promote it to be your primary db:

```
heroku pg:promote HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE_URL
heroku pg:psql
```

More info on promote is located here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#pgpromote

Answer (score -1):

When running

```
heroku pg:psql DATABASE_URL
```

heroku tries to connect to the URL : DATABASE_URL, which obviously doesn't exist, it does read the ENV var DATABASE_URL

So if you're in the folder of your app, simply running

```
heroku pg:psql
```

is enough, otherwise, you can specify the app

```
heroku pg:psql --app <YOUR_APP>
```

And then heroku will read the DATABASE_URL var from the app it's connecting on.

Comment: I have DATABASE_URL, and the datbase does exist. Why did it show that error?